# R Error: could not find function "join_all"

Tags: r, plyr

I'd like to use the join_all() function from plyr, but keep getting the 'Error: could not find function "join_all"'. I have loaded plyr with "library(plyr)" or "require(plyr)" and can use other functions from the package without any problems. Any idea what the problem could be?

Thanks a lot,

mce

Below some test-code:

```
df1 = data.frame(CustomerId=c(1:6),Product=c(rep("Toaster",3),rep("Radio",3)))
df2 = data.frame(CustomerId=c(2,4,6),State=c(rep("Alabama",2),rep("Ohio",1)))
df3 = data.frame(CustomerId=c(1,3,6),Phone=c(rep("110",2),rep("112",1)))
library(plyr)
join(df1, df2, type = "full", match = "all") # This works fine.
#Joining by: CustomerId
#  CustomerId Product   State
#1          1 Toaster    <NA>
#2          2 Toaster Alabama
#3          3 Toaster    <NA>
#4          4   Radio Alabama
#5          5   Radio    <NA>
#6          6   Radio    Ohio

dfs <- list(df1, df2, df3) 
join_all(dfs) # this does not work
# Error: could not find function "join_all"
```

Comment: It works for me.  I use `plyr_1.8.1`.  Try `plyr::join_all(dfs)`

Comment: Same here - works fine on version 1.8.1.  What version are you using?  Try updating.

Comment: OK. I was still using plyr_1.7.1. Seems join_all is a new feature in version 1.8.1 Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

You have loaded plyr after dplyr - this is likely to cause problems.
If you need functions from both plyr and dplyr, please load plyr first, then dplyr: library(plyr); library(dplyr)

I guess you follow the course, and load the dplyr package before you load the package plyr. Therefore, try library(plyr); library(dplyr) , and you will solve this problem.

Hope this helps.